# Why do I receive an error when the I use name.replace('N','n') instead of name.replace("N","n")

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

The following block of code throws an error:

```
greeting = 'Hello'
name = 'Nisarg'

message = f'{greeting}, {name.replace('N','n')}. Welcome!'

print(message)
```

But, the following block of code seems to work perfectly:

```
greeting = 'Hello'
name = 'Nisarg'

message = f'{greeting}, {name.replace("N","n")}. Welcome!'

print(message)
```

Single quotations and double quotations can be replaced with each other in Python, but, why is it an issue here.

Comment: Because you're trying to include single quotes inside a string that is delimeted by single quotes.  The first single quote inside the string ends the string literal.

Comment: If you did `f"{greeting}, {name.replace('N','n')}. Welcome!"`. It wouldn't have been a problem. You were not using quotes correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SO highlighting should give you a clue. Single and double quotes are indeed replaceable, but you're *already* using single quotes around the string as a whole; so when Python encounters another single quote, it interprets it to mean that you are ending the string.

This is exactly why there are multiple ways of quoting strings in the first place.